# Unable to get context and access schema from a database

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-database

I'm following the [Android developers](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) tutorial to set up a database but I'm having an issue. This is my schema file :

```
public final class ContactsDBSchema {

    public ContactsDBSchema(){};

    public static abstract class ContactsEntry implements BaseColumns
    {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "contacts";
        public static final String COLUMN_CONTACT__ID = "contact_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_CONTACT__NAME = "contact_name";
        public static final String COLUMN_CONTACT__PHONE = "contact_phone";

    }

    public class ContactsDBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contacts.db";

        public String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "create table" + ContactsEntry.TABLE_NAME + ContactsEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT__ID +"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + ContactsEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT__NAME + "TEXT," + ContactsEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT__PHONE + "TEX";

        public String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + ContactsEntry.TABLE_NAME ;

        public ContactsDBhelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
            onCreate(db);
        }

        public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
        }

    }
}
```

The issue now is when I'm trying to access it from another class like this one:

```
public class ContactsDBprocess {

    ContactsDBSchema.ContactsDBhelper contactsHelper = new ContactsDBSchema.ContactsDBhelper(getContext());

}
```

I'm unable to access the helper class properly. The `getContext()` function does not work and I get an error:

> Cannot resolve method `getContext`

I tried doing this:

```
ContactsDBSchema.ContactsDBhelper contactsHelper = new ContactsDBSchema.ContactsDBhelper(this)

ContactsDBSchema.ContactsDBhelper contactsHelper = new ContactsDBSchema.ContactsDBhelper(getApplicationContext())
```

I still don't have any luck. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: In what class are you trying to instantiate `ContactsDBhelper`? You need to pass a valid `Context` as the constructor param.

Comment: Your `ContactDBProcess` class needs to either be defined in a class that has `getContext()` or it needs to extend such class. Or you can pass a valid `context` to its constructor and then use that variable instead of `getContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to access to your application context from anywhere in your project would be to define a method inside your Application sub-class like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{
   private static Context context;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(){

      super.onCreate();

      MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();


   }

   public static Context getAppContext(){
      return MyApplication.context;
   }
}
```

**NOTE**

If you were not already extending the `Application` class in your project, you can do so but remember to set the name of your application in `AndroidManifest` to the subclass you have created above (`MyApplication`).

From here, you we be certain to have access to the context anywhere!

```
MyApplication.getAppContext();
```

Good luck and I hope this helps you!